# Is there a simple way in javascript to test for "null or not an object" error in IE8

Tags: javascript, error-handling, internet-explorer-8

For a long time, I've trusted a lot of code examples showing supposedly allowed 'safe" detection of unavailable objects or object properties. Two quick examples include getting the available with/height of a screen like this...

```
var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

Or  maybe to make sure a service or procedure was available, so I could take alternate action, examples including...

```
 if (!window.event) // do something else
 if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) // do something else
```

I didn't make up any of the above tests, but took them from answers here on stackoverflow, often from high rated answers. Yet when I run code with constructs on this on IE8, The script will stop, and the debugger will spit out errors like...

```
'window.event' is null or not an object 
'window.XMLHttpRequest' is null or not an object 
'window.innerWidth' is null or not an object
```

And of course they aren't "warnings'.. they are errors which stop everything. So I guess there is no EASY way to test these kinds of objects or object properties in IE8? I suppose I could put try/catch blocks surround every line of code that might possibly cause a 'null or not an object' complaint, but its definitely going to make my library a lot bigger, and probably slower! And conditional compilation constructs such as this don't seem to work very well...

```
<!--[if gte IE 9 | !IE ]>-->
 // do something only if !IE or IE > 8
<!--<![endif]>-->
// resume normal inclusion? usually not reliably!
```

So in the examples I've given that caused the errors, what can I do to make the code safer for browsers that don't support the objects, just using plain vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since support for the "in" operator stretches all the way back to IE 5.5 (at least according to this MDN reference article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), you might try something like this:

```
if ('event' in window || 'innerWidth' in window || 'XMLHttpRequest' in window) {

    // Do stuff...

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try and run some tests. For sanities sake, I won't attempt Supporting lower than IE8 unless its a very simple issue. But the fact that something as widely used as "if  (window.event) " is failing, I'm suspicious that somewhere in my code I'm accidentally clobbering the whole "window" object. I've done it before just by stupidly thinking i could create a local var called 'window' LOL!

Comment: Yes! This does work and definitely seems to be both a safe way to test, and has to be way faster that any try/catch block could have been! Thanks again!